# Container div not showing borders plus left and right divs dont have full bg color coverage

Tags: html, css, border

I have a container div with a left and right column div inside.
Problem is that the left and right divs within container1 make it so that container1 has no borders and also conainer1s bg color is only present within the size of right and left divs. Eg: if right div has 45% and left has 50% width then container1's bg will not show for the last 5% width.

Just using container1 without left and right leaves off only the bottom border.

I need all the left, right and bottom borders to be present and for the bg color of container1 to cover 100%.

Next issue is that Ive made a fiddle and am unable to reproduce the issue meaning something in my code is conflicting with this. However i don't expect anyone to go through my entire code looking for the answer but to suggest anything that comes to mind that might be the conflict.

Here is the fiddle which doesn't suffer the issue http://jsfiddle.net/3cz06ydg/

```
<div class = "container1">

<div class="left-column1">

<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </div>
    <div class="right-column1">
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">   
</div></div>

body {

        background-color: #b0c4de;
    } 

    .container1 {
    width: 100%;
    border: 5px solid #006699;
    background:#0A3D5D;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    padding-top:4px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:4px;
    clear:both;
    border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
    border-top-right-radius:none;
    border-top-left-radius:none;
    }
    .left-column1 {
    width: 95%;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom:8px;


    }
    .right-column1 {

    width:95%;
    float:left;

    padding-left:2px;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width:400px) {
    .left-column1 {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;}


    }
    .right-column1 {
    float:left;
    width: 48%;
    }

    }

    .container {
    width: 100%;

    }
```

Here you can see the issue at work on the right side of the page:
http://www[dot]techagesite.com/hd-stargate-sg1-mobile-phone-wallpaper-1080x1920.htm

Comment: Anyone? My site looks shite while this issue persists. Just have a look at my sites page (not the fiddle)

Answer (score 0):

now see this work i think your problem solve :

[**Demo WOrk**](http://jsfiddle.net/tapos00/3cz06ydg/1/)

```
body {
    background-color: #b0c4de;
} 

.container1 {
width: 80%;
border: 5px solid #006699;
background:#0A3D5D;
float:left;
padding-bottom:4px;
padding-top:4px;
padding-right:0px;
padding-left:4px;

border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
border-top-right-radius:none;
border-top-left-radius:none;
}
.left-column1 {
width: 95%;
float:left;
padding-bottom:8px;


}
.right-column1 {

width:95%;
float:left;

padding-left:2px;
padding-bottom:8px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:400px) {
.left-column1 {
float:left;
width: 50%;}


}
.right-column1 {
float:left;
width: 48%;
}

}

.container {
width: 100%;

}

<div class = "container1">

<div class="left-column1">

<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </div>
    <div class="right-column1">
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">   
</div></div>
```

Comment: I need container1 to be 100% :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `DOCTYPE` from:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

To:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

is [this the result](http://postimg.org/gallery/3hekcgfge/) you're after or have I misunderstood your question?

The borders are show on every side (second pic show bottom border) , the container1 takes up 100% of the page.
Sorry, but not enough rep to upload pics.

Comment: hope the edit helps. If this is what you were looking for, let me know!

Comment: Also, I can help you make the two containers take up 100% ( http://postimg.org/image/stzh4e3c9/ )

Comment: More wallpapers and advertisements for example don't have the border around the container like follow us does. Also follow us background takes up the whole container but more walls and advertisements plus anything else that has the left and right-column1 within the container doesn't. I need the big to take up the whole container and the borders to show up as well. Does this make sense?

Comment: hey, yea I'm here. Ok so I understand now that you have two divs inside some of the divs of the right column... which is something, since I didn't understand that we were talking about those. Now, which are the divs with the problem- I think (like to share?) and (follow us) are ok ?

Comment: Ok its the latest wallpapers, more wallpapers, facebook pages and make money ones. They all suffer the issue as they are all the same container. Now interestingly im having an issue where many images arent showing up in firefox and chrome desktop but they are on my mobile. My partners chrome mobile browser is missing only the c1-c5 images and only shows the border radius outline. Im not sure whats going on but its making me a little crazy

Comment: Got the images fixed, its been a looooong week. I have to say this has to be the most annoying issue ive ever had. Its almost been a week and still no reason why the borders are gone and the background not filling the entire container.